# How to limit in Cloud Firestore security rules

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm making a charity app that uses the Firebase SDK to directly talk to Cloud Firestore from within the application

Anyone (user or not) can create a charity, every charity is located in a city.

If the user adds a new one, I want to stop the other users from creating a new charity for 30 minutes in the city he created the charity in.

And I think this is the way to implement the 30 minute duration but how can I make it in each city

```
match /charity/{document=**} {
  allow create: if isCalm(); 
  request.time > resource.data.timestamp + duration.value(30, 'm');
 }
}
```

If you didn't understand here's an example : let's say i have 3 cities (A B and C) , if the user create a charity in city A i want to stop anyone from creating charities in city A for 30 minutes ..

Comment: Please post your database structure screenshot so that we can test code as per that. Also post the code by which you are currently posting new charity created details in the database.

Comment: thanks for your comment i think the one who answered is right maybe i can't handle it with rules

Comment: You have to use cloud functions. I can help with that if you agree to use cloud functions..

Comment: well that's a great idea , i don't know about cloud functions so will try to read and learn about that , thank you so much

Comment: Alright let me know when you are ready. If you watch Firecasts on Youtube [official videos from firebase] you'll learn quickly. They are best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you can handle this with rules... And if you can when an user will try to create a new charity it will trown an exception witch is not a good practice...
You're better to add a TimeStamp to your Firestore document, get the document and verify if 30 minutes have past

Comment: thank you so much , i thought about that but i didn't try it yet .. will do and get backto this answer , thank you man

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried this myself.

If you have 1 collection, called Cities, and in that, a subcollection called charities. Then, when you access your specific charity subcollection to go and write a new charity document, a security rule can ensure that parent (city) field meets your condition of at least 30 minutes. You would have to create a new field, `lastModified` or `lastCharityCreatedAt` in the city document. This way, you don't need cloud functions.

**In summary:** keep track of the last write, in a parent document so you can check it when you need to.